# Can't get mod_expires to work on an EC2 Bitnami image

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-ec2, bitnami, mod-expires

I've been unable to successfully get a client's website to set expires. They're running a bitnami cloud image on an EC2 instance. 
Things I've tried:

  1. Loading the mod_expires module into apache with httpd.conf

    Specifically:    "LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so"

  2. Using the wordpress plugin "W3 Total Cache"

    This plugin fails to detect the mod_expires module, but I am fairly sure that it ships with bitnami

  3. editing .htaccess directly

    Using     ExpiresActive On  ExpiresDefault "access plus 90 days"

  4. The tutorial here: http://www.theitbaby.com/wordpress/2013/10/14/optimizing-bitnami-for-pagespeed-insights-and-gtmetrix/

Strangely, apache complains when I use the code provided in the above mentioned tutorial gives me an error saying that ExpiresByType takes two arguments. When I change "access plus 9 months" to "A2592000" it seems to go back to working.

I'm out of options left to try and low on hope. Any ideas?

**Solution:**
1) configure .htaccess to use mod_expires [as can be seen here]http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/apache-module-mod-expires)
2) change httpd-app.conf to use AllowOverride All

Answer (score 0):

Setting "AllowOverride All" presents a security issue and should be avoided. I solved the same problem by using "seconds code" syntax, although I can't explain why the alternative syntax did not work.

Use A7776000 instead of "access plus 3 months"

Example:

> ExpiresActive      On
>   ExpiresDefault     A7776000

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably because .htaccess is disabled in bitnami build by default (see [Understand .htaccess on bitnami](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/use-htaccess/)). You may check whether the `AllowOverride` option is set to `None` in your httpd.conf. If it is, then .htaccess is disabled. Therefore, you need to move the content in `.htacess` to `<your-wordpress-folder>/conf/htaccess.conf`. Don't forget to restart apache.